# MySQL running very slowly on local IP Server running Windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have installed MySQL on Machine running Windows 7. That system is dedicated for MySQL and SVN only. No-one else is using that system except I have remote access to that system for setups and taking backups etc.

This machine is running on local IP address, which is `192.168.0.150`.

I can connect to MySQL installed on that machine through 3306 port and using IP as host instead of `localhost`. Everything is working fine.

But the issue we are facing that it is very slow. I mean sometimes it is very fast like I am running queries on my own system and sometimes it gets very slow that even small select query doesn't work.

I have also tried through SQLYog. SQLYog is IDE like MySQL Workbench.
I have tried running queries directly from SQLYog on my machine on database running on other machine, which we call server.

So same issue, only 4 people accessing MySQL having same usernames and passwords from 4 different PCs.

I don't understand why it can't handle only 4 users, and why it sometimes becomes so slow. That is Core2Duo System with 4GB ram on which we have MySQL installed.

I have installed MySQL through MSI installer from MySQL website. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: @Mihai
What i am trying to say it any query we run, sometimes this server or machine running mysql runs the query very slow and sometimes as fast as it should work.. it dosen't matter what query we do.. small or big..

Comment: What is your network card speed? Try setting the server card speed to 100Mbps full-duplex. Also make sure the network card power settings are set so that the card never goes to sleep.

Comment: Sounds like the machine goes in hibernate state, check as @Kinnectus mentioned and screensaver etc.